# Why don't these JavaScript loops work as expected?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a seeder function for my mongoose database, the code I've written so far actually works, I just can't understand the order in which operations are performed. this the source code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Book = require('./models/book'),
    Chapter = require('./models/chapter');

var books = [
    {
        title: '12 Rules For Life',
        author: 'Jordan B. Peterson',
        cover: '',
        ISBN: 1241232,
        description: 'A self-help book written by Canadian psychologist Jordan B. Peterson',
        status: 'reading'
    },
    {
        title: "Charllote's Web",
        author: 'EB White',
        cover: '',
        ISBN: 1243575,
        description: 'The story of a girl who raises a pig and a spider',
        status: 'read'
    },
    {
        title: 'A Fraction Of The Whole',
        author: 'Steve Toltz',
        cover: '',
        ISBN: 1241686,
        description: 'A book telling the story of three generations of the Toltz family',
        status: 'want to read'
    }
];
var chapters = [
    {
        title: 'First Chapter - How It All Began',
        body: 'This is how it all began'
    }
];

function seedDb() {
    // delete all books and chapters
    Book.deleteMany({}, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Removed all books');
            Chapter.deleteMany({}, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Removed all chapters');
                    // add new books to the database from books array
                    books.forEach(function(book) {
                        Book.create(book, function(err, createdBook) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            } else {
                                console.log('Created The Book ' + createdBook.title);
                                // add new chapters to the book created
                                for (var i = 0; i < chapters.length; i++) {
                                    Chapter.create(chapters[i], function(err, createdComment) {
                                        if (err) {
                                            console.log(err);
                                        } else {
                                            console.log('Created chapter for ' + createdBook.title);
                                            createdBook.chapters.push(createdComment);
                                        }

                                        createdBook.save(function(err) {
                                            if (err) {
                                                console.log(err);
                                            } else {
                                                console.log('Associated Chapter with the book ' + createdBook.title);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

module.exports = seedDb;
```

this is the order in which operations take place:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2DZP.png)

shouldn't the order be something like this:

- Removed all books
- Removed all chapters
- Created the book 12 rules for life
- Created chapter for 12 rules for life
- associated chapter with the book 12 rules for life
- and so on

Comment: That's quite hard to read. Consider using Promises instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance the model methods are promises itself. he just needs to add `async` before his `function` and write it like this `await Book.deleteMany({});`

Comment: This is a classic example of callback hell with loops inside of asynchronous operations where you lose all control of when things happen.  This should be rewritten entirely with promises and you can then make code that looks nice, is easy to follow, can be controlled and has actual error handling (you've blown off all possible error handling in this code).  Literally, start over after converting ALL your asynchronous operations to use promises (or use the promise interfaces built into the libraries you are using).

Comment: Before you even try to understand the problem you have with loops, go and spend some good amount of time learning how to not depend on callback hell. Basically studying async/await and promises. This should be a much higher concern for you right now.

Answer (score 0):

## Use async await  and use let instead var scope issue

```
async function seedDb(){
  try{
    await Book.deleteMany({});
    await Chapter.deleteMany({});
    for(let book of books){
      const createdBook = await Book.create(book);
      for(let chapter of chapters){
        if(createdBook.chapters) createdBook.chapters.push(chapter);
        else createdBook.chapters = [chapter];
        await createdBook.save();
      }
    }
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to replace the `.forEach()` loop with a plain `for` loop both to control sequencing and to allow for proper error handling.